# getting plain array text when updating mysql record

Tags: php, mysql

so i have table with fields like this, i want to be able to edit each username/email etc if check box selected.

```html
echo '<td><input type=checkbox name=checkbox[]  value='. $row['Id'] .'       ></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text     name=username[]  value='. $row['username'] .' ></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text     name=email[]     value='. $row['email'] .'    ></td>';
echo '<td><input type=text     name=adress[]    value='. $row['adress'] .'   ></td>';
```

and this is my script, i get array plain text as result from each input, btw Im using query for email only to test first

```html
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        $id_array = $_POST['checkbox']; 
        $id_count = count($_POST['checkbox']);
        for($i=0; $i < $id_count; $i++) {
            $id = $id_array[$i];
            $query = ("UPDATE members SET email = '". $_POST['email'] ."' WHERE ID = '". $id ."'");  
            $result = $conn->query($query); 
            if($result) {
                echo "ok";
            }
            else {
                echo "<br><br>Error: " . $conn->error;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your qiestion is unclear and please format code so that it will be lookable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Secondly, you're stuffing your POST array directly into the query, which is incorrect. Since you're using the `[]` naming hack in the form fields, `$_POST['email']` is going to be an ARRAY of values from your form, and you need something more like

```
.... VALUES ('$_POST[email][$i]', ...)
                           ^^^^
```

(note the extra array index) to access the individual values in that sub-array.

Remember, for PHP, using an array in a string context gives you the literal word `Array`, and not the array's contents:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3);
echo "$foo"; // outputs 'Array'
echo "$foo[1]"; // outputs '2'
```

Comment: hello Marc B thanks for reply, this is not going online I'm just learning PHP but its good to understand security issues